# Azure free website with Python Django not running

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

Since Azure now gives us 10 free website I thought I'd try my hand at something new in the form of Django.

I used jetbrains' PyCharm to create a new Django site. Created an empty site on Azure, added a MySQL database and set the connection string in the settings.py file. Then I ran the syncdb command which asked me all the right questions and created the tables.
I fired up webmatrix told it to open a site based on a folder and gave it the path to the Django app. Now I don't know how to tell it to use python as the handler for web requests? Does anyone know if this is possible or not? The guides that are up on the azure site are for deploying to a virtual machine as opposed to the free website magic.
I tried installing the templates from helicon tech (http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/) but it kept failing on the helicon dependency. I figure it's because I'm using the Win 8 preview.

Judging by the stuff on the Windows tab for this page https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-app-with-django/ I don't suspect it's going to be likely, ah well wordpress it is then :(

Although there is always IronPython and MVC

Comment: Same problem, I tried this tutorial: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/ and doesn't work, I get "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: You can create a Django app from the Azure Web Sites gallery. Works perfectly. I'm posting this in 2014, so I'm not sure what things were like in 2012 when you originally posted your question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it does support creating Django based projects under the free tier.

> Windows Azure Web Sites provide limited free hosting and rapid deployment – and now you can use Python!

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can do Django in the VM and "Cloud Service" (webrole) contexts:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-app-with-django-and-mysql/

and

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/django-with-visual-studio/

Support for 'Web Sites' is being worked on.

Comment: Hey Sean,
Where did you get the information about the web site support being worked on? Could you supply a link please?